# How to propagate onClick event from fragment to activity when using FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this fragment:

```
class FooFragment extends Fragment {

  FooListener mListener;

  interface OnFooListener {
    void onFoo();
  }

  class FooListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View view) {
      mListener.onFoo();
    }
  }

  void onAttach(Context context) {
    Assert.assertTrue(context instanceof OnFooListener);
    super.onAttach(context);
    mListener = (OnFooListener) context;
  }

  void onCreateView(...) {
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
  }
}
```

`FooFragment` expects the Context to be an instance of `OnFooListener`, and the `onClick` event is propagated using this mechanism up to the Activity (in my case), which is the context.

The Activity that 'owns' the fragment is the context of FooFragment, because I declared `<fragment>` in my activity layout (that's how I understand it).

Now, I want to put this fragment inside swipe views, which I implemented following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). A class inherits from `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside an Activity, is responsible for handling the fragments, for example:

```
class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    LocalAdapter adapter = new LocalAdapter(getSupportFragmentAdapter());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  class LocalAdapter extends FragmentPagerSupport {
    static LAYOUTS[] = {
      new DebugFragment()
    };
    int getCount() {
      return LAYOUTS.length;
    }
    Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return LAYOUTS[position];
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fit `FooFragment` inside this class such that I can propagate the event up to TabsActivity? I don't understand what is the context of my fragment in this case.

I could put a setter but this would mean that I need specific handling of this particular class in `LocalAdapter`, which seems bothersome the more I need interactions between the fragments and the parent activity.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your fragment you can do something like this (note the cast):

```
   onClick() {
       ((TabsActivity)getActivity()).myMethod();
   }
```

Comment: I opted for this solution: I use `getActivity()` instead of `context` in `onAttach()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a similar scenario and to simplify the code, we choose to use an event bus library.

The library that best served us was EventBus from GreenRobot, but there are many others.